# Tensorflow - GridLSTM + Dynamic RNN - How to deal with dynamic shapes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I'm a beginner using Tensorflow and I started in a handwriting recognition task. Currently, I'm testing the GridLSTMCell (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/GridLSTMCell) and I'm facing some problems when trying to initialize the dynamic RNN with this type of recurrent cell.

```
cell = rnn.GridLSTMCell(num_units=num_units, feature_size=feature_size, frequency_skip=frequency_skip, num_frequency_blocks=num_frequency_blocks, forget_bias=1, state_is_tuple=True)
outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, seq_len, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Apparently, the problem is due to a restriction present in GridLSTMCell, which can only deal with inputs with static shape, but as you can see below, in my case the batch_size can vary since I have a training set with batch_size=1 and a fixed test set with 100 examples.

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,IMAGE_ROWS,IMAGE_COLUMNS],name="inputs")
```

Given this scenario, I wish to know if someone has a workaround, maybe some tip to define the inputs with fixed batch_size = 1 and yet be able to apply the model to a test set with 100 examples. Some answers present in a similar question ([Tensorflow Grid LSTM RNN TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442025/tensorflow-grid-lstm-rnn-typeerror)) is related to another Grid LSTM implementation in TF.

Sorry about my poor English, I appreciate the support.

Thanks in advance!